# Gimp Keeps Crashing

Tags: macos, firefox, crash, gimp

I can do 2 maybe 3 things in Gimp then it crashes. Most of the time it just closes, and I have to reopen. After it crashes 3 times then when I reopen it the third time, the wheel on my cursor just spends (Mac OS X)
I re-downloaded Gimp (I have the latest version) hoping it would help, but now it seems worse. Can someone please help?
I'm on a Mac OS X, and Firefox. I've been using Gimp since 1998 V1.0, and I have never had this problem before

Comment: Hi! Any other specific information you can give would be very helpful in diagnosing your problem. What actions can you take before GIMP crashes? Is it any action or a specific set of tasks? It would probably also be useful to know what version of OS X you're using, and *especially* what version/build of GIMP you're using (e.g. gimp.org, gimp.lisanet.de, etc.).

Comment: On a related note, if you're using the gimp.org version, try the one at gimp.lisanet.de, or vice versa. It might be there's enough of a difference that your problem is fixed.